# Changing background colour of different blocks

Tags: html, css, mailchimp

I'm creating what should be a basic email template in Mailchimp and wanted to change the background color of one block to be different from the others (this will be white, the other block backgrounds will be blue.)

I was thinking of trying to use CSS to do this, as it is not possible in Mailchimp to have multiple background colours in the body, which is where I'm having trouble as someone who does not code.

I want to change the background color of the block to white and would like to know where to enter the background color into the HTML code listed below. I'm also wondering if I need to export this code into notepad or something instead of editing from mailchimp HTML editor also.
Code:

```html
<table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="min-width:100%;" class="mcnBoxedTextContentContainer">
  <tbody><tr>
    <td style="padding-top:9px; padding-left:18px; padding-bottom:9px; padding-right:18px;">
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnTextContentContainer" width="100%" style="min-width: 100% !important;background-color: #007E97;">
        <tbody><tr>
          <td valign="top" class="mcnTextContent" style="padding: 18px;color: #FFFFFF;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;font-weight: normal;line-height: 150%;text-align: center;">
            <h1 dir="rtl" style="text-align: left;"><font face="helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, verdana, sans-serif">LOREM IPSUM</font></h1>
            <table align="center" bgcolor="#fefefe" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#eaedef" width="100%">
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The background color for the table is set here:

```
   <table border="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnTextContentContainer" width="100%" style="min-width: 100% !important;background-color: #007E97;">
```

You can see the field background-color: #007E97, the # means it's a color code so changing this to #FFFFFF means pure white.

But you probably also want to change the text color, otherwise you will have white text on white background, the text color can be found in:

```
<td valign="top" class="mcnTextContent" style="padding: 18px;color: #FFFFFF;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;font-weight: normal;line-height: 150%;text-align: center;">
```

Here you have the field color: #FFFFFF, if we can change it to #000000 (black) instead.

```html
<table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="min-width:100%;" class="mcnBoxedTextContentContainer">
  <tbody><tr>
    <td style="padding-top:9px; padding-left:18px; padding-bottom:9px; padding-right:18px;">
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnTextContentContainer" width="100%" style="min-width: 100% !important;background-color: #FFFFFF;">
        <tbody><tr>
          <td valign="top" class="mcnTextContent" style="padding: 18px;color: #000000;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;font-weight: normal;line-height: 150%;text-align: center;">
            <h1 dir="rtl" style="text-align: left;"><font face="helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, verdana, sans-serif">LOREM IPSUM</font></h1>
            <table align="center" bgcolor="#fefefe" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#eaedef" width="100%">
            </table>
```

As for how you should export I don't really know since I haven't used Mailchimp but you could probably just copy the code into any code editor and then name the file index.html, open it in your browser and when you're happy with it paste the code back into Mailchimp.